# writing modified XML element in python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm trying to modify an xml field in an OFX export file. The producer of the export doesn't produce a unique key for the fitid filed in the file, so I want to replace that field with a unique key generated from two other fields in the xml.

I've got as far as the following code, but can't work out how to write the new FITID field.

A sample of the XML file is:

```
    <BANKTRANLIST>
                <DTSTART>20130705</DTSTART>
                <DTEND>20130805</DTEND>
                <STMTTRN>
                    <TRNTYPE>DEBIT</TRNTYPE>
                    <DTPOSTED>20130708</DTPOSTED>
                    <TRNAMT>-7.99</TRNAMT>
                    <FITID>08072013660</FITID>
                    <NAME>HARE HATCH SHEEPLANDS    </NAME>
                    <MEMO>Effective date: 06/07/2013</MEMO>
                </STMTTRN>
                <STMTTRN>
                    <TRNTYPE>DEBIT</TRNTYPE>
                    <DTPOSTED>20130708</DTPOSTED>
                    <TRNAMT>-6.75</TRNAMT>
                    <FITID>08072013660</FITID>
                    <NAME>BINGHAMS BREWERY LIMIT   </NAME>
                    <MEMO>Effective date: 06/07/2013</MEMO>
                </STMTTRN>
                <STMTTRN>
                    <TRNTYPE>DEBIT</TRNTYPE>
                    <DTPOSTED>20130709</DTPOSTED>
                    <TRNAMT>-282.5</TRNAMT>
                    <FITID>09072013660</FITID>
                    <NAME>WWW.DVLA.GOV.UK          </NAME>
                    <MEMO>Effective date: 08/07/2013</MEMO>
                </STMTTRN>
                <STMTTRN>
                    <TRNTYPE>DEBIT</TRNTYPE>
                    <DTPOSTED>20130715</DTPOSTED>
                    <TRNAMT>-84.78</TRNAMT>
                    <FITID>15072013660</FITID>
                    <NAME>BP TWYFORD CONNECT       </NAME>
                    <MEMO>Effective date: 12/07/2013</MEMO>
                </STMTTRN>
                <STMTTRN>
                    <TRNTYPE>DEBIT</TRNTYPE>
                    <DTPOSTED>20130715</DTPOSTED>
                    <TRNAMT>-25.1</TRNAMT>
                    <FITID>15072013660</FITID>
                    <NAME>WHITE HART SHERFIE       </NAME>
                    <MEMO>Effective date: 13/07/2013</MEMO>
                </STMTTRN>
    </BANKTRANLIST>
```

My python attempt is:

```
    from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

    datafile = '/Volumes/Data/Projects/moneydance fix/statement20130805.ofx'

    tree = et.parse(datafile)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for stmtrn in root.iter('STMTTRN'):
    amount = stmtrn.find('TRNAMT').text
    date = stmtrn.find('DTPOSTED').text
    fitid = stmtrn.find('DTPOSTED').text
    print "amount: ", (amount.split('.')[0])[1:]
    amount = (amount.split('.')[0])[1:]

    fitid.text = (date + amount).ljust(12,'0')
    print 'New fitid: ', fitid

    tree.write(datafile+'new')
```

Comment: Can you show the output of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that for fitid, you don't want the `text` of the element, you want the element itself. So, you don't want to do `stmtrn.find('FITID').text` but rather `stmtrn.find('FITID')`. This will make your assignment, `fitid.text = ....` work as expected.

And you most certainly don't want to do `fitid = stmtrn.find('DTPOSTED')` which I believe is a typo in the code you pasted.

Try this code:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

datafile = 'statement20130805.ofx'

tree = et.parse(datafile)
root = tree.getroot()
for stmtrn in root.iter('STMTTRN'):
  amount = stmtrn.find('TRNAMT').text
  date = stmtrn.find('DTPOSTED').text

  print "amount: ", (amount.split('.')[0])[1:]
  amount = (amount.split('.')[0])[1:]

  fitid = stmtrn.find('FITID')
  fitid.text = (date + amount).ljust(12,'0')
  print 'New fitid: ', fitid.text

tree.write(datafile+'new')
```

Comment: Thanks @audiodude, that works the way I expected (or rather wanted). And yes, it was a typo in my code. Long night...